# Present the Schauder basis in $c(\mathbb{R})$ and $c_0(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Present the Schauder basis in $c(\mathbb{R})$ and $c_0(\mathbb{R})$

The space $ c(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of all sequences of real numbers that converge to some limit. The Schauder basis for this space consists of sequences where each element of the basis has a one in one position and zeros in the rest, and also includes a sequence converging to one.

$$e_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0, \dots)$$
$$e_2 = (0, 1, 0, 0, \dots)$$
$$\dots$$
$$e_n = (0, 0, \dots, 1, \dots)$$
$$e_{\infty} = (1, 1, 1, 1, \dots)$$

Space $c_0(\mathbb{R})$ - This is a subspace of the space $c(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all sequences that converge to zero. The Schauder basis for $c_0(\mathbb{R})$ is similar to the basis for $c(\mathbb{R}) $, except for the sequence converging to one. That is, it consists only of sequences with one one and the rest zeros.

$$ e_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0, \dots) $$
$$ e_2 = (0, 1, 0, 0, \dots) $$
$$ \dots$$
$$ e_n = (0, 0, \dots, 1, \dots) $$

Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Not "The" but "A" Schauder basis. And where are your doubts precisely? Didn't you check that your solutions agree with the definition? https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Comment: Does this apply to my question? I have two bases

Comment: This applies to your main question (for $c$). The other one is a corollary. But again: better write down your own proofs and tell us where you think you might be mistaken.