# Give an example of an incomplete non-separable Euclidean space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Give an example of an incomplete non-separable Euclidean space that does not have an orthonormal basis.

The space $\ell^2(A)$ consists of all functions $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ for which the sum of squares $\sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a)^2$ is finite. The scalar product in this space is defined as $\langle f, g \rangle = \sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a)g(a)$. This space is not separable, since the set $A$ is uncountable, and therefore it is impossible to construct a countable dense subset in it. Without separability, it is impossible to construct an orthonormal basis in the usual sense, since any orthonormal basis must be countable or have the cardinality of a continuum

Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Could you add further justification for the statement "The space is not separable, since $A$ is uncountable" ? It is not true in general for example that an uncountable topological space is not separable(if it were then seperability would  be a useless concept anyway) also, could you clarify how the sum of squares is even defined for an uncountable index set?

Comment: Could you give your own example?

Comment: So, did I give the right example?

Comment: Dmitry, you are correct that if the Hilbert dimension $|A|$ of the [Hilbert space $\ell^2(A)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#General_%E2%84%93p-space) is uncountable, then that space is not separable. However, that space is complete. And what do you mean by "Euclidean space"? For me, a Euclidean space is finite-dimensional (hence separable, complete, and having an orthonormal basis). As for "orthonormal basis", do you really mean a linear (Hamel) basis, or rather a Hilbert basis?

Comment: Hilbert space...

Comment: A Hilbert space is complete by definition. You probably rather mean inner product space. And what about your meaning for "orthonormal basis"?

Comment: No idea about what you have in mind when writing 'Without separability, it is impossible to construct an orthonormal basis in the usual sense, since any orthonormal basis must be countable or have the cardinality of a continuum". Can you please edit your post to explain?

Answer (score -2):

This sounds good. To solve the exercize, you need a Hilbert space that is not complete, so just take any non-closed subspace of $l^2(A)$ for instance take all the functions that are supported on any finitely many coordinates.

It is not separable, because it includes $1_a$ for all $a\in A$ (taking the value $1$ on $a$ and zero otherwise). This is an uncountable set of elements with $\|1_a - 1_b\|=1$ whenever $a\not = b$.

It is not complete because if you choose some $a_n\in A$, then the sequence $f_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} 1_{a_k}$ is Cauchy but does not have a limit (because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}1_{a_k}$ does not exists).

Comment: Thank you!

Could you take a look at this problem?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828639/present-the-schauder-basis-in-c-mathbbr-and-c-0-mathbbr

Comment: There is not such thing as a "Hilbert space that is not complete". Inner product space -- yes, but not Hilbert space. For the same reason - "non closed Hilbert space" makes no sense.

Comment: What does sub-Hilbert space mean? Can you provide a link to Wikipedia or an explanation of this definition?

Comment: And you didn't say anything about the orthonormal basis

Comment: @Dmitry by orthonormal basis, you mean a countable basis?

Comment: @uniquesolution right thank you